# How to Check Registration Expiration of User and send Notification by email in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I have a user registration form which has an expiration date. Within which the user needs to Activate his account within say within 30 Days of registration. Now i want to send him notification to such users who registered but not yet activated his account. I want to send him AUTOMATED EMAIL after each 10 Days. Say if user Registered at 1 Jan 2012 the notification email must be sent on 10 Jan 2012 that "Plz activate witin 20 Days" if current date is 20 JAN 2012 then " Plz Activate within 10 Days".(WITHOUT HUMAN INTERVENTION) i.e no need to click button to send mail. just must act as monitoring service.

Which is the best method to send email on Specified Interval and by which means using SQLSERVER or through Windows Service?

Plz Suggest me the right method!

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can run scheduler at regulat interval.
You can use followinf library for scheduling.You can do it easily by scheduling from Web Server itself.By calling 1 aspx page only.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/